# submit button not working

Tags: php, html

I'm using the following form, but when I press the submit button it doesn't navigate to a different page

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" align="right">
 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <?php display_msg(); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="26%"  style="padding-left:5px"><a href="?page=<?php echo $page_number; ?>&amp;<?php echo $name; ?>">Name</a></th>
      <th width="40%"><a href="?page=<?php echo $page_number; ?>&amp;<?php echo $email; ?>">Email</a></th>
      <th width="7%">&nbsp;</th>
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"></td>
<?php
// Check if delete button active, start this
if($delete){
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=del.php\">";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not set delete.php as the action of your form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `if($delete){` to `if(isset($_POST['delete'])){`.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
```

You have not defined an action in your form.

Comment: A form without an action will default to itself.

Comment: From the way the question is phrased I thought that that was the problem at first.